# how to insert multiple selected items from listbox to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have two listboxes and i want to insert multiple selected values from both listboxes to database.
Let me explain :-

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlSuperior" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlSubordinate" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
```

and a submit button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

Suppose i select 2 values from ddlSuperior and 1 value from ddlSubordinate.
How can i do that..?

Comment: What's the problem, what have you tried?

Comment: On submit button click, i want to insert - 2 selected values from ddlSuperior and 1 selected value from ddlSubordinate to a database 'tblPosition' with columns - id,superior and subordinate.

Comment: It means one id has two superiors and one subordinate

Comment: You have one column for superior  but the user must select two? I would suggest to add another superior column then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are quite a few ways.

```
    Dim superiorIndexes = ddlSuperior.GetSelectedIndices
    Dim vals = superiorIndexes.Select(Function(i) ddlSuperior.Items(i).Value)
    Dim subordinateIndexes = ddlSubordinate.GetSelectedIndices()

    vals = vals.Concat(subordinateIndexes.Select(Function(i) ddlSubordinate.Items(i).Value))

    For Each val As String In vals

        ' Code to do db insert

    Next
```

Find db example here: [C# SQL insert command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218867/c-sharp-sql-insert-command)  Look at Marc_S answer.