# Fill data in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am new to SQL and I am experimenting.

I have created a SQL Server Project in VS2013 and generated several tables using the GUI (using the auto-generated `CREATE TABLE` command).

Now I want to implement in C# a stored procedure to populate the tables with data statically before the deployment.

Could someone give me an example/link about how to do that?

Comment: [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [The Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) will get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of the syntax you can use to use SQL together with C#:

```
string stmt = "INSERT INTO dbo.Test(id, name) VALUES(@ID, @Name)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, _connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = i;
    cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = i.ToString();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Source: [C# SQL insert command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218867/c-sharp-sql-insert-command)

Comment: What is _connection?(I want to statically populate the table before the deployment)

Comment: Sorry, "_connection" is a previously declared SQL connection.  For example:  
Using _connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)  
  
So the syntax is as follows:  
SqlCommand [alias name] = new SqlCommand([SQL statement], [sql connection])

Comment: The tables are not on the server.I want to populate them and only after that deploy to the server.So I don`t think i need a conection ....

Comment: @Yakov, even if you have tables created LOCALLY in SQL Server, you can have a connection string, such as:  
    "Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Data Source=(local);"