# Remove bad characters from columns with string values

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am writing an INSERT query that inserts a large amount of values into a table. Alas, I cannot use parameterized queries in this special case.

So I would like to have a function to remove all bad characters that lead to an INSERT failure. E.g. in the following query

```
INSERT INTO myTable (a,b,c) VALUES ("a","b","c")
```

If the value of `a` contains a quote `"`, this will probably ruin the entire INSERT. So is there a function to remove all these risky characters? Otherwise, what are the characters that are dangerous?

Comment: _Why_ can't you use sql-parameters?

Comment: @TimSchmelter because I don't have a single INSERT. My INSERT looks something like `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);` with thousands of rows inserted at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use sql-parameters to prevent any injection in your script:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO myTable (a,b,c) VALUES (@a,b,@c)", conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", "a");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", "b");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", "c");
```

Comment: My problem is that I am not running a single INSERT. It's something like `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);` with thousands of rows inserted at once.

Comment: @all Sorry It was typo ...rectified now  but that would have also worked fine:)

Comment: @Pedram why can't you just put the sqlcommand into a loop, using the one connection?

Comment: @user1666620 Correct me if I am wrong but isn't an INSERT with multiple rows faster than multiple INSERTS with one row?

Comment: @Pedram http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218867/c-sharp-sql-insert-command - if you want performance, use BulkInsert : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: @user1666620 I think we have a different case here. In the link you provided, the user is running single INSERTS in both cases. In our case, we have one INSERT with multiple values versus multiple INSERTs that insert one row.

Comment: @Pedram I edited the comment and included Bulk Inserts. Either way, you have an answer as to how to do parameterize your query.

Comment: @user1666620 that bulk insert is an MSSQL command. My question is MySql.

Comment: @user1666620 no I don't have an answer because parameterized queries don't work in my case as I explained above.